# Python3 & PyCharm - Debug logging levels in run/debug

Tags: python, debugging, logging, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm just starting with PyCharm, is there a way to show debug & info warnings?

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('tipper')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

warn, error, critical all show:

```
/home/username/someproject/.someprojectenv/bin/python3/home/username/someproject/go.py
warn message
error message
critical message

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However debug, info do not show.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with PyCharm, but with how logging configuration works. If you try to write the code you have shown in a normal python interactive session you get the same output:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger('tipper')
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logger.debug('debug message')
>>> logger.info('info message')
>>> logger.warn('warn message')
warn message
>>> logger.error('error message')
error message
>>> logger.critical('critical message')
critical message
```

The problem is that *setting the `logger`'s level isn't enough*! You must also add a handler to the logger otherwise the logger will simply forward the message up the chain. The messages will end up at the `root` logger, which has, by default, a level of `logging.WARN` and thus discards `DEBUG` level messages.

However if you add a handler to `logger` all works fine:

```
>>> logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
>>> logger.debug('test')
test
```

You can set more than one handler for each logger and each handler can have a different logging level.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17668633/510937) question for a bit of further information about logger's and handler's levels. I'd suggest also to read carefully the documentation for the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module and the various guides (e.g. the [`logging` How-To](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/logging.html), because it has a really advanced configuration.

Also from python3.2 there's a [`dictConfig`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) function which allow you to specify the configuration for your logging hierarchy as dictionary, without having to manually create every handler and logger by hand.

Comment: @diimdeep What does that mean? As it currently stands your comment isn't constructive and could be flagged and deleted. If you want to somehow evaluate the value of an answer/question you should upvote/downvote it. If you don't understand an answer and what some clarification, or you found a different problem related to the answer you should add a comment *explaining* what's wrong with the current answer. Otherwise you simply have a *new question* which you should ask. So which one is it?

Comment: For logging while running tests in PyCharm see

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470062/how-can-i-see-log-messages-when-unit-testing-in-pycharm

Answer (score 4):

Very dirty workaround just to get it run is to overwrite the logging functions.
It may come in handy sometimes you just want to take a quick look without setting the whole debug level.

**!DONT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION!**

```
logging.debug = print
logging.info = print
```

Comment: sucks that pycharm doesn't have a setting to do this for you. i feel it would improve dev experience substantially

Answer (score 4):

```py
import logging
import datetime

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)8.8s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(),
              logging.FileHandler(f'log/{datetime.datetime.now().isoformat().replace(":", "-")}.log', encoding='utf-8')],
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Ad [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22615542/2111778) said, Python's default log level is `WARNING`, because otherwise the output would just get swamped.

Complementing their answer, one can also use `basicConfig` as demonstrated above. This modifies the settings of the **root** logger which all other loggers inherit from, meaning you don't have to set DEBUG in every file in your project. Note that libraries you import will also log on this level (unless you explicitly exclude them). This will do nothing if the root logger has already been initialized, unless you pass `force=True`.