# Not able to log to two different places using Python logging module

Tags: python

Forgive me, still learning how to use the `logging` module. So, I have two handlers, one to log everything to a file and one specifically to log the message when triggered into Hipchat.

I don't quite understand what it means to have root vs non-root loggers. As it is below, it will write what I want to my log file AND displays both messages into the hipchat room. So I found another stack post that says to create two multiple "non root loggers." So I tried it with `logger = logging.getLogger('test1')` and `hipchat_logger = logging.getLogger('test2')` but there's no message in Hipchat (it does write to the log file).

```
logger = logging.getLogger()    
hipchat_logger = logging.getLogger()

# File handler
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("mylog.log", "a")    
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Hipchat handler
hipchat_handler = hiplogging.HipChatHandler(MY_TOKEN, CHATROOM)
hipchat_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
hipchat_logger.addHandler(hipchat_handler)

# Testing
logger.info("Hi, this is a test. I should not see this in Hipchat")
hipchat_logger.info("Hi, display me in Hipchat")
```

Comment: Does this work with only HipChatLogger ?

Comment: By itself you mean without the `logger` handler, then yes it does. It's only when I have multiple handlers.

Comment: `assert logger is hipchat_logger` → True shows that you are getting the same logger from both (static) calls to `logging.getlogger()`. You need to instantiate another logger with something like https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLoggerClass

Comment: Oh, I just looked at the code, but the text says, that you did all that what we proposed. So maybe try something like `logger=logging.getLogger()` with `hipchat_logger=logging.getLogger('hipchat')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in the first two lines. "Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.", cf. [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects).

So a solution would be (modified after discussion in comments):

```
logger = logging.getLogger()    
hipchat_logger = logging.getLogger("hipchat")
```

**EDIT**

After more research on this topic: The problem is certainly not the missing root logger. There is a problem with [loglevels](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel):

> Logging messages which are less severe than lvl will be ignored. When a logger is created, the level is set to **NOTSET** (which causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger). Note that the root logger is created with level **WARNING**.

So what does happen here?

```
# implicit root logger with loglevel WARNING

# both child-logger: loglevel NOTSET
logger = logging.getLogger('file')
hipchat_logger = logging.getLogger('hipchat')

# ...create and add file handler...

# change 'file'-loglevel to DEBUG
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# ...create hipchat handler...

# change loglevel of the handler(!) to DEBUG.
# 'hipchat'-loglevel is still NOTSET
hipchat_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# ...add hipchat handler ...

# logger -> loglevel DEBUG -> INFO gets logged.
logger.info("Hi, this is a test. I should not see this in Hipchat")

# hipchat_logger -> loglevel NOTSET -> delegate to root-logger
# root-logger -> loglevel WARNING -> INFO not logged (being below threshold)
hipchat_logger.info("Hi, display me in Hipchat")
```

So to solve this issue, either explicitly set the loglevel of root logger to DEBUG (as in the code above). Or simply set the loglevel of the second logger accordingly:

```
hipchat_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

A question that might remain is answered elsewhere: [What is the point of setlevel in a handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668633/what-is-the-point-of-setlevel-in-a-python-logging-handler)

Comment: I've tried this, please read the last sentence before the sample code.

Comment: @luckytaxi yep, I realized it, as commented in your question.

Comment: I got it working. your solution in the comment works :-) If you want to modify your answer I will accept it. I left the `logger` handler empty and passed a name to the `hipchat_logger` handler.

Comment: ok thats nice. I wonder though, why the "two non root solution" does not work with hipchat. I did a test with two sub-loggers, which work (python 2.7).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the additional research and explanation. Makes complete sense now.

Answer (score 3):

One with your code problem is that calling `logging.getLogger()` multiple times returns the same logger.

```
# both of these are same logger instances
logger = logging.getLogger()    
hipchat_logger = logging.getLogger()
```

To get two different instance, give different names to different loggers. Also, with no name parameter, you get the root logger.

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()

logger = logging.getLogger("file")
hipchat_logger = logging.getLogger("hipchat")

#now getting the logger with same name will return same logger
this_is_same_as_logger = logging.getLogger("file")
```

Comment: I've tried this, please read the last sentence before the sample code.

Comment: @luckytaxi As you figured out and also written in my answer... you must have an instance of root logger.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't realize I had to set a root logger. Most examples I've seen had parameter based loggers.

Comment: Yup... I think this happens only when you need multiple loggers in the same module... probably to maintain proper propagation.