# Log to sys.stdout from a module logger

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have the following simple test script:

```
import logging
import sys


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'$
logger.addHandler(handler)


logger.info('Hello World!')
logger.warning('Bad!')
```

I run this script with `python test.py` in the command line. I get:

```
__main__ - WARNING - Bad!
```

When I expected to get:

```
__main__ - WARNING - Bad!
__main__ - INFO - Hello World!
```

E.g. I expected both the `info` and `warning` log messages to get printed to the console window, but only the `warning` message did. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [What is the point of setLevel in a python logging handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668633/what-is-the-point-of-setlevel-in-a-python-logging-handler) contains answer.

You need to `setLevel` on `logger` itself too, its level (default WARNING) will not allow messages from it's handlers with lower level than set in parent-logger.

Handler is there to filter messages.

Answer (score 2):

This should work?

```
import logging
import sys


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)


logger.info('Hello World!')
logger.warning('Bad!')
```

You should be setting the `setLevel` on the `logger` object.

Thanks